# Select multiple items from ListView and reoder them together

Tags: flutter, listview, draggable, reorderable-list

I have a working ReorderableSliverList solution but I need to be able to select multiple ListView items then reorder them in one go.

So if I have a list of 10 items and I drag items with index 5, 8, and 9 to the top they will become 0, 1, 2 and the rest will follow suit.